# Conflict in Case Condition in Sql Server query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
select  CASE when  (select distinct BR.BorrowerID from tblBorrow BR 
inner join tblWorker W on W.ContractorID=BR.BorrowerID 
inner join  tblBorrowWorker TWB on  TWB.WorkerID=W.WorkerID 
inner join tblBorrowWorkerAssign TBWA on TWB.BorrowWorkerAssignmentID=TBWA.BorrowWorkerAssignmentID where TWB.WorkerID=11276) then 'BR.BorrowerID'   else 'NotBorrowed' end as BorrowedStatus
```

Here actually in 'Then' Condition i want to display the BorrowerID,here the subquery part is working well and returning ID ,but when i add with CASE statment its giving an Error
"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'."This query is a part of my stored Procedure.What will be the solution

Answer (score 1):

CASE clause expects a boolean condition. Can you use Exists() to check for true condition? Try using exists() for inner select statement (starting with `select distinct BR.BorrowerID from tblBorrow BR...`)

Comment: so where i will place exists,in inner query

Comment: Something like `select  CASE when Exists (< select statement that results in true/false value>)`

Comment: Ya its working  great thank u...,but at then condition i want to add the ID i mean BorrowerID instaed of'Yes' or'True' because in UI level i want to show the Name,but here hw i add BorrowerId

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to show the value of `BR.BorrowerID` from the subquery instead of the `'BR.BorrowerID'` string constant, you could try the following (assuming you've ensured that the subquery returns no more than one row):

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT CAST(BR.BorrowerID AS varchar(15))
      FROM tblBorrow BR 
      INNER JOIN tblWorker W ON W.ContractorID = BR.BorrowerID 
      INNER JOIN tblBorrowWorker TWB ON TWB.WorkerID = W.WorkerID 
      INNER JOIN tblBorrowWorkerAssign TBWA ON TWB.BorrowWorkerAssignmentID = TBWA.BorrowWorkerAssignmentID
      WHERE TWB.WorkerID=11276
    ),
    'NotBorrowed'
  )
```

On the other hand, if that was a full query (not a part of a bigger one) in your post, the following might also be an option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CAST(BR.BorrowerID AS varchar(15)), 'NotBorrowed')
FROM
    (SELECT 1) x (x)
    LEFT JOIN
        tblBorrow BR 
        INNER JOIN tblWorker W ON W.ContractorID = BR.BorrowerID 
        INNER JOIN tblBorrowWorker TWB ON TWB.WorkerID = W.WorkerID 
        INNER JOIN tblBorrowWorkerAssign TBWA ON TWB.BorrowWorkerAssignmentID = TBWA.BorrowWorkerAssignmentID
    ON TWB.WorkerID = 11276
```

The `(SELECT 1) x (x)` "table" is only there to ensure the resulting set is not empty in case the right side of the left join returns no rows.